# Query String Webpart Timeout

Tags: 2010, web-part, query-string

I added a Query String (url) Filter Webpart to my page. It added quickly. But when I try to configure it, it seems to spin forever. It finds the parameter I want to filter on, and when I click done and close the modal window, it never completes the action. It seems to spin forever.

I've tried different users and got the same effect. I have checked ULS and did not see anything out of the ordinary.

Any thoughts on this are appreciated.